# Convert System::String to char* in function with StringToHGlobalAnsi

Tags: string, char, c++-cli, interop, mixed-mode

I need many conversions in my CLI wrapper from `System::String^` to `char*` and I've written a function, but I can't free the heap space before returning the `char*`! (get heap errors over the time)

**Conversion**

```
char* ManagedReaderInterface::SystemStringToChar(System::String ^source)
{           
    char* str2 = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(source);

    return str2;
}
```

I use the function like:

```
GetSomething(SystemStringToChar(str), value);
```

Any ideas?!

Comment: can you use `char*` instead of `System::String` in the first place. since you are doing 'many' conversions

Comment: It's a wrapper for a native C++ class and yes it should be a System:String in CLI functions!

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately, someone needs to be responsible for freeing the memory that your return value is stored in. It can't be your conversion function, as it will return before you want to free the memory.

This is all made easier if you use `std::string` instead of raw `char*`s. Try this:

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
...     
GetSomething(msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(str).c_str(), value);
```

Comment: That's just an example - if you really want to use `char*` then you can create a custom `raii` wrapper that will free the memory when it goes out of scope.

Comment: I had this problem and your answer solved my solution.  Also, Thank you StackOverflow.com for having a more effective search engine than Google on these matters due to recognizing punctuation

Answer (score 2):

In every single method:

```
IntPtr memHandle = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(string);

try
{
    char *charStr = static_cast<char*>(memHandle .ToPointer());

    // do something with charStr

    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(memHandle); // free space -> Attention: don't delete it to soon
}
catch
{
    ...
}
```

It should be clean now!

Comment: `free space -> Attention: don't delete it too soon`
I just want to know. Because my app crashes randomly somewhere here.